# javascript regex with long strings

Tags: javascript, regex

The string that i have is

```
[<span class="link" nr="28202" onclick="javascript:openAnlaggning('/kund/Bridge/Main.nsf/AnlOkatSamtligaFaltCopy/045C9DDFDC7AB308C1257C1B002E11F1?OpenDocument&urval=1');" >Alingsås Järnvägsstation</span>]
```

The logic is to check if there is a '[' at the start of the string and if it is present then take the value between the square brackets. In the above string what i would like to get as output is

```
<span class="link" nr="28202" onclick="javascript:openAnlaggning('/kund/Bridge/Main.nsf/AnlOkatSamtligaFaltCopy/045C9DDFDC7AB308C1257C1B002E11F1?OpenDocument&urval=1');" >Alingsås Järnvägsstation</span>
```

I tried with this

```
var out = value.match('/\[(.*)\]/i');
```

[image]

I tried it on scriptular.com,and i do get a match.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a problem explanation.

Comment: @Jack `value.charAt(0)` will solve further problems with IE.

Comment: @VisioN Yeah, never mind that, because `substr()` doesn't work in the way I had hoped =(

Comment: @Jack [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) does that trick `;)`

Comment: @hari your regex won't work if another `]` is present, See my answer.

Comment: @VisioN Yup, gotta love the three different ways to carve out substrings ;-)

Comment: @VisioN it works for the current input only.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Provide an example where it won't work. `(.*)` is not a lazy match, so it will do the job fine.

Comment: @VisioN see http://regex101.com/r/qD4hI0

Comment: @AvinashRaj Which is fine, as the OP wants to get everything between first and last square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes to make the argument a real [regular expression literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression):

```
// -------------------v --------v
var out = value.match(/\[(.*)\]/i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below regex to get the values inside `[]` braces,

```
\[([^\]]*)\]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vA7oD2)

Your regex `\[(.*)\]` will not work if there is another `]` at the last. See the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/qD4hI0).

For this you have to make your regex to do a  non-greedy match by adding `?` quantifier next to `*`,

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kR9pN9)